# Does apple accept my application with placeholder image while downloading images from server ?

Tags: iphone, image, placeholder

I have iphone application in which I am downloading images from server & displaying it in table cell. I am downloading 10 images at a time. So I am using **"PLACEHOLDER"** image while image is downloaded from the server. Once image is downloaded , I am replacing placeholder image with actual downloaded image.

My question is , is it ok to use placeholder image ? Does Apple will accept my application with Placeholder image?

Sorry for my bad english.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: why not ? the placeholder image is an image, isn't it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, apple will accept placholder images. I use them in all my apps when downloading images.

Comment: Thanks. Do we have any restriction on Placeholder image like format,size,dimensions? Also can you show me some application on App Store using Placeholder image?